# Append a tuple to a list of tuples in python

Tags: python, list, append

I want to add a tuple in a list of tuples:

```
list1 = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
tuple1 = ('e', 'f') # this is the tuple I want to add to the list above (list1).

list2 = list1.append(tuple1)

print(list2)
```

The result should be:

`[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]`

But instead, I'm finding:

`None`

Comment: `list.append` is an _inplace_ method for lists. It returns nothing and changes the list you call it on (here, list1). If you do `list2 = list1.append(tup1)`, then list2 will be None. Instead, print `list1`. And if you really don't want to do that operation _inplace_, you can do `list2 = list1 + [tuple1]`

Comment: The way I solved this. Was by adding the list 1 to a new list that contains de tuple1. Finally, I changed the order.

```
list1 = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
tuple1 = ('e', 'f')

list2 = [tuple1]
for i in list1:
    list2.append(i)

list2.sort(key=tuple1.__eq__)

print(list2)

```

Anyone has a better and more "pythonic" solution?

Comment: Thank you, Mateo Vial. I really appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You just did!
Check out your list1

```
list1=[('a','b'),('c','d')]
list2 = list1.copy()
list2.append('e','f')
print(list2)
```

Explanation

- list.append() method just returns None